# time complexity of merge sort

Tags: algorithm, merge

why the time complexity of best case of top-down merge sort is in O(nlogn)?
i think the best case of top-down merge sort is 1, only need to compare 1 time.
how about the time complexity of bottom-up merge sort in worst case, best case and average case.

One more question is  why each iteration takes exactly O(n)? could some one help with that?

Comment: `O(1)`? Maybe `O(n)` by preprocessing and checking the array is already sorted.

Comment: "best case" means, "best case given that the size of the input is `n`", not "best case assuming that there are only 2 items to sort".

Comment: Describe your algorithm that you think it O(1) and we can probably tell you where it is wrong...

Comment: @Chris Unless the algorithm turns out to be some kind of a bucket sort, there's no "probably" :)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort for all the information you probably want (amazing what google will do for you).

Answer (score 5):

> why the time complexity of best case of top-down merge sort is in
>   O(nlogn)?

Because at each iteration you split the array into two sublists, and recursively invoke the algorithm. At best case you split it exactly to half, and thus you reduce the problem (of each recursive call) to half of the original problem. You need log_2(n) iterations,  and each iteration takes exactly `O(n)` (each iteration is on all sublists, total size is still `n`), so at total `O(nlogn)`.

However, with a simple preprocessing to check if the list is already sorted - it can be reduced to `O(n)`.

Since checking if a list is sorted is itself `O(n)` - it cannot be done in `O(1)`. Note that the "best case" is the "best case" for general `n`, and not a specific size.

> how about the time complexity of bottom-up merge sort in worst case,
>   best case and average case.

The same approach can give you O(n) best case to bottom up (simple pre processing). The worst case and best case of bottom up merge sort is `O(nlogn)` - since in this approach the list is always divided to 2 equally length (up to difference 1) lists.

Comment: why the iterations should be log_2(n)? is there any formula for this? and one more question is regarding to the binary tree, why the length of the binary tree is log(n).

Comment: @Justin: at the deepest level of the recursion you have 1 element. The 2nd level you have 2. The 3rd level you have 4, the 4th level you have 8, .... at the i'th level you have 2^(i-1) element. So we are looking for `i` such that `2^(i-1) = n`. since `2^logn == n`, we conclude `i = logn+1` - so the total number of iterations is `O(logn)` The same holds for binary trees

Comment: what you mean by having 1 element,2 elements? do you mean that at first, there is a list of array, secondly, it is separated into two parts, so on so far..

Comment: @Justin: This is how merge sort works, at the deepest level (the stop clause) you have one element. At the level before it 2 elements, ... Each level of the recursion is working on some sublist of the original, this sublist is of the length I described (1,2,4,...2^(i-1))

Comment: thanks! got it, and how about the worst case? from the book:the design and analysis of algorithm. why the worst case of is neither of two arrays becomes empty before the other one contains just one element? rather than splitting the input not exactly two half?

Comment: one more question, why each iteration takes exactly O(n)? could you explain it in detail?